Getting flickering or fading issue in the component while using react-pdf/renderer npm package
I am using the react-pdf/renderer npm package in one of my project Jobshorn.com with next.js ,where I enter some text it will display in the pdf viewer in the other part of the screen, I am facing the flickering or fading problem after entering the text in the text field and after that only i can see the data on the screen, need suggestion on solving the same issue
For the reference attaching the issue video and code
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/18cVvc07XXFHlti2PtCSpxu2yy_T4c-1M/view?usp=sharing)
code link
I have tried, debounce method, Use memo and loader and nothing has worked out so need suggestion to overcome it or any other npm package which helps me out for my implementation

Please update the above question by adding some minimal code, which produces this issue.
